# Sending location of GSM modem through SMS

Tags: gps, sms, location, gsm, at-command

I was wondering if anyone has any experience in finding the location through GSM. I can't use GPS and I don't have access to wi-fi. My searches have shown that I will probably need the CellID and AT commands. However I am trying to automate this entire process so this is where I'm stuck. Essentially, I would like to have the modem/computer automatically send its location to my phone on a periodic basis. And does anyone know of an API to work with AT commands?

Thanks

Comment: first you have to get a modem that supports AT command and then create a batch file to get the CellID and send it in a sms to your number and create a scheduled task to run this batch up to your daily basis

Comment: @MaveRick Thanks for the reply. I have a modem already which I set up using AT commands and Windows HyperTerminal. However, I'm not sure how the batch file would be able to send the AT commands to the modem.

Comment: Actually i'm not a guru using `HyperTerminal` and i'll leave this question to be answered by the specialists, But i'll leave my suggestion in case that you didn't find a way or a proper answer for your question, my suggestion is to use linux OS+(.pl Or.py)script to catch the `CellID` and send it back through the modem as a `SMS` to your mobile No., in my career i have seen something like that but i'm not sure how to do it, but google is a good place to start, search for a compatible modem with some linux distribution and then start your script in `Python` which is pretty easy language to learn

Answer (score 0):

You can get cell id from several commands, `AT+CREG`. `AT+CGREG` and `AT+CEREG`. See the [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) specification for more details.